# Correct punctuation on a caption for a series of photos

Tags: punctuation

I want to include a caption for a series of photos. The caption should say "Vesper...plotting." Is this correct? For context, it is a series of photos of my cat hunting an insect inside the house.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of punctuation is really a matter of style more than anything else. Using ellipses here is slightly unusual. Used here, they would normally indicate a pause in conversation or thought rather "stand in" for missing text (the other use for ellipses.)

As a textual *description*, there's no clear indication that you are saying or thinking anything. However, it could be interpreted that way. (Especially if you consider a photographic caption as being the same thing as the text "speaking" the words to a viewer.)

Perhaps some more *common* ways of punctuating the caption would be:

> Vesper, plotting.
>   Vesper: plotting.
>   Vesper is plotting.
>   Vesper. Plotting . . .

But there is nothing *wrong* with the punctuation as you have it. Especially if your other captions are punctuated in a similar way, establishing a pattern.

Also, they are your photographs and you can caption them however you wish. (Unless they are publication submissions.)